# jQuery - page refreshing after click

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following jQuery method, to do something when i click the button with the id 'add':

```
$(function () {
   $('#add').on('click', function () {
     $('#headline').text("Hurra!");
   });
})
```

When i add a breakpoint in chromium, i can see that it enters the method, changes the content of the headline, and then changes it back to its original state for some reason (that happens while the debugger is in the minified jquery script, so i don't really know what's happening). Can anyone give me a hint on what might be going on?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you provide more details on your issue? http://codepen.io/fz0718/pen/GNvWYq

Comment: It seems to reload the page after it completes my method. I already tried adding e.preventDefault(). Funny, my code seems to be exactly as in the snippet that you linked, yet it doesn't work. I will take a closer look and try to uncomment anything iIdon't need right now.

Comment: can you please provide your html code

Comment: I added it to this pen, now it has the same behaviour in the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqXrvW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the page is refreshing because the form is getting submitted.

if you dont want it to submit, use `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();`

```
$(function () {
  $('#add').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#headline').text("Hurra!");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! I did add e.preventDefault before, but i put it in the beginning of my method. That didn't work. Can you explain why?

Comment: it should have. it doesnt matter where. it could of been that you didn't specify the parameter as `e`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to have been the problem. Thank you!